# ASP.NET MVC 4 SimpleMembership missing roleManager, etc in web.config

Tags: asp.net, mysql, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

I understand the whole membership approach is supposed to be easier in MVC 4.
However, this is proving to be very time consuming in getting this to work.

Case in point: The example at http://blog.longle.net/2012/09/25/seeding-users-and-roles-with-mvc4-simplemembershipprovider-simpleroleprovider-ef5-codefirst-and-custom-user-properties/ shows a modification to the System.Web section of the web.config, namely that one adds the WebMatrix type to the roleManager section.  However, I have no role manager section in my web.config.  This is a fresh project.

What did I miss along the way?

Second, what I ultimately want to do is hook up SimpleMembership to my MVC 4 project, and have custom profile fields.  And I need to do this against MySQL.  I've read that the universal data providers allow for this, but does anyone have one simple, single tutorial on how to do this?

I really do hope that things really are more "simple" in MVC 4 than they were in MCV 3.

Answer (score 0):

SimpleMembership provider won't work with MySql - have to extend the ExtendedMembershipProvider and implement the methods, etc... to work with mysql/EF.